# Unable to get a Window, abort on macOS(Kivy error)

Tags: python, macos, kivy

I am on macOS catalina
preview version of kivy 2.0
python 3.8

im getting the following error:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc3, git-313e219, 20200722
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.3 (v3.8.3:6f8c8320e9, May 13 2020, 16:29:34) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.1
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer (img_sdl2 ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/hidapi.framework/Versions/A/hidapi
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/.dylibs/SDL2
  Reason: image not found
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the developers version and it works fine.